# How to hold the mutiple values of type in HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to create a HashMap with Single Key and it should hold multiple values of type String,ArrayList,String,ArrayList ..

ie.., Msg of type String,groupdestId of type Integer ArrayList,id of type String,userdestId of type Integer ArrayList..

```
HashMap<String,String> body = new HashMap<>();
body.put("message",Msg);
body.put("groupdestId",groupdestId);
body.put("id",id); 
body.put("destId",userdestId);
```

Comment: You should create a class with these values as fields instead.

Comment: Do those 4 values have any relationship together? If they belong together and describe an object you shouldn't use a map at all and rather have a custom class that holds those 4 values.

Comment: Are you sending the data to an API? Could you tell us why you're actually doing? There could be better solutions like the one proposed by @OHGODSPIDERS.

Comment: @Sufian yea I am sending the data to the API using retrofit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply define the `Map` as

```
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
```

A `Map<String, Object>` can hold any kind of value so also:

- `String`
- `ArrayList<Integer>`

This solution give you the most flexibility if you don't know what values (type and name) you need to store.

---

If you know exactly what data you need to handle a better solution is to define a custom class having properties named as the keys of the Map.

```
public class DataHolder {
    private String message;
    private List<Integer> groupdestId;
    private String id;
    private List<Integer> userdestId;

    // Add getters and setters
}
```

Additionally if you know that those data don't change values over time a better solution is to create an [immutable class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) so it can be shared in a multithreading environment without syncronize access to them.

Comment: why ever this got a downvote, its correct as everything inherits `Object`

Comment: @AjayJayendran you are wellcome.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer sometimes happens that people with a different or incorrect idea downvote also correct answers. Could be interesting that people with more points can give a different factor of upvote than others, but this is not the case today.

Comment: The example he has given strongly suggests that he should make a class with the values he needs to store. Don't use a `Map` in this case!

Comment: @marstran The question is very clear _I need to create a HashMap with Single Key and it should hold multiple values of type String,ArrayList,String,ArrayList .._

Comment: The answer will do what the question asks (hence the down vote is not mine) but it subverts the type system and makes it difficult to handle the values because you have to test them to find out what type it is.

Comment: @JeremyP if you don't know numbers, names and kind of values you need to hold a Map<String, Object> is the better solution.

Comment: I think an answer should lead the guy who asked to the correct __solution__. Just blindly answering the question as if this is the best practice, is not good.

Comment: @marstran if you think to have a better answer why you don't write it so the questionaire can evaluate it? This is the best to do in this case instead of add not constructive comments.

Comment: Suresh Atta's answer is what I'm looking for. I'm not going to rewrite his answer ;) I think my criticism is very constructive here. Creating a map containing `Object`s surely isn't the best thing to do here. There's a reason we have classes in Java.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO We don't know there are allways 4 values of the same type and name or if it is a completly variable list of attributes. Asking for clarification about the requirements would have been the better solution instead of playing [Fastest Gun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

First Make a WrapperClass where you declare dataType.

```
Class StringAndListWrapper{
    String stringValue;
    List<String> stringListValue;
    public StringAndListWrapper(){
       stringValue = new String();
       stringListValue = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Then you can put wrapper in HashMap,

```
String Key = "your key";
HashMap<String, StringAndListWrapper> hmap = new HashMap<>();
StringAndListWrapper stringAndListWrapper = new StringAndListWrapper();
stringAndListWrapper.stringValue = "putYourStringValue";
stringAndListWrapper.stringListValue.add("add Elements Here");
hmap.put(key, stringAndListWrapper);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to store multiple types

```
HashMap<String,Object> body = new HashMap<>();'
```

Generally mixing types discouraged and make sure that while getting back the values you need to check properly. Otherwise you end up in class cast exceptions.

---

Moreover you need an object and not map because as I can see all the keys are related. Just create a class and use that class to store these attributes.

```
public class Body {

private String message;    
private int groupdestId;
private int id;
private List<String> vals;

// other attributes and getters/setters


}
```

Comment: Great answer that explains why creating the untyped map is discouraged.